# How to use @Observable in Xcode 15 Beta?

Tags: swift

I just downloaded Xcode 15 beta on my developer machine running the first beta of macOS Sonoma.

I want to port my View Model class from `@ObservableObject` to `@Observable`.

However, when I try to add the new attribute, I get an error message:

```
@Observable final class ViewModel {
    
}
```

> Unknown attribute 'Observable'

I deleted the original Xcode version, I selected the beta version using `Xcode-select` after running `sudo xcode-select --reset`. Nothing seems to work.
I also installed the command line tools for Xcode 15 manually.

When running `swift -version`, I get the following output:

```
swift-driver version: 1.82.2 Apple Swift version 5.9 (swiftlang-5.9.0.114.6 clang-1500.0.27.1)
Target: arm64-apple-macosx14.0
```

What am I missing? Is this not supported yet in the first beta of Xcode 15?

Comment: Make sure your project only supports iOS 17+

Comment: It is a macOS only app and the deployment target has been set to macOS 14 (for testing purposes I created a brand new project with Xcode 15 which automatically selects macOS 14).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to import the Observation framework:

```
import Observation

@Observable final class ViewModel {
   // more code here
}
```

Source: [@Observable and other SwiftUI Macros](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/731077)

Comment: Thank you. I thought it is part of the SwiftUI framework.

Comment: Welcome, yes I assumed this as well, glad I could help!

Comment: I missed that one too, luckily found this question and answer. I find it frustrating though that they don't include the `import` stmt in the documentation and in the examples there–that's where it belongs imo...

Comment: Despite my minimum deployment being iOS 17 and importing Observation, the `Unknown attribute 'Observable'` error persists for me.

Comment: lhunath can you share your code?